# How to make automatic shift of elements at hit on them of the menu

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Initially, everything looks like this. The categories are on the left. I use bootstrap for dishes and generally on the site.
You can suggest how to do this: when opening a category, you need to do a shift of dishes to col-md-offset-3.

[image]

For example, if there are more categories / subcategories, then you need to do the offset further for the dishes that are on the left. The problem is that I do not know how to do it at all. Do instead of me do not need to, at least tell.

[image]

And now I have his work.
The code is better to look if to expand result on all screen

```js
var blockRect = document.querySelector('.block').getBoundingClientRect();
var foods = document.querySelectorAll('.food');

function toggleSubCategories(_category, init) {

  if (!init) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.subcategory').forEach(function(category) {
      if (category !== _category) {
        category.classList.remove('show');
      }
    });

    _category.classList.toggle('show');
  }

}

function isOpenListStructure() {
  return document.querySelectorAll('.subcategory.show').length === 0 ? false : true;
}

function foodOffset(category, init) {
  var subcategories = document.querySelector('.list-structure > ul');
  var offsetListToFood = subcategories.offsetHeight - blockRect.height;
  toggleSubCategories(category.children[1], init);
  var isOpen = isOpenListStructure();

  if (subcategories.offsetHeight >= blockRect.height) {
    
    foods.forEach(function(food, index) {
      var nextFoodIndex = index;
      var foodRectData = food.getBoundingClientRect();
      
      // detect left foods
      if (foodRectData.left <= blockRect.left) {
        var absoluteFoodHeight = foodRectData.height + foodRectData.top;
        var absoluteListHeight = subcategories.offsetHeight + Math.abs(subcategories.getBoundingClientRect().top);
        
        console.log(food, 'subcategories.offsetHeight ', subcategories.offsetHeight, ' > ', foodRectData.top, ' && ', subcategories.offsetHeight, ' < ', absoluteFoodHeight);
        
        if ( absoluteListHeight >= foodRectData.top && absoluteListHeight <= absoluteFoodHeight ) {
          food.classList.add('col-md-offset-4');
        } else {
          food.classList.remove('col-md-offset-4');
        }

      }

    });
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll('.food').forEach(function (food) {
      if (food.classList.contains('col-md-offset-4')) {
        food.classList.remove('col-md-offset-4');
      }
    });
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('.category').forEach(function(category) {
  foodOffset(category, true);
  category.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    foodOffset(this, false);
  });
});
```

```css
.list-structure {
  position: relative;
}

.list-structure li {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.list-structure li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 11px 10px 7px 31px;
  display: block;
}

.list-structure li {
  display: block;
  background: #546a88;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.list-structure > ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100% height: 100%;
}

.categories {
  padding: 10px;
}

.subcategory {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}

.food {
  padding: 10px;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 categories">
    <div class="list-structure">
      <ul>
        <li class="category">
          <a href="#">Маки/Суши</a>
          <ul class=" subcategory">
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="category">
          <a href="#">Салаты/Супы</a>
          <ul class=" subcategory">
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="category">
          <a href="#">Салаты/Супы</a>
          <ul class=" subcategory">
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="category">
          <a href="#">Салаты/Супы</a>
          <ul class=" subcategory">
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="category">
          <a href="#">Горячие блюда</a>
          <ul class=" subcategory">
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="category">
          <a href="#">Десерты</a>
          <ul class=" subcategory">
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="category">
          <a href="#">Напитки</a>
          <ul class=" subcategory">
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 block">
    asdsakjdslkajdklsad
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when the category "Напитки" is expanded, the first block is shifted, this is correct, but the next one is left in place, and 3 is shifted.

I know that this is due to a shift, but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: your code snippet needs to include bootstrap css and js files in it. Take a look at it. It doesn't show anything in result.

Comment: @Chirag updated